# XamlParseException for resources from different assembly

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have in my solution a project that is only used to provide resources to all other projects. I import a resource in a XAML file from that project like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Common.Ui;component/Resources/MetroIcons.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Common.Ui;component/Resources/SyncfusionIcons.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

When I do that everything looks good in the VS designer (VS 2013), but when I run the application I get a XamlParseException, and I cannot figure out from the stack what's wrong.

I tried, alternatively, to put the resources in a folder in the same project and import them like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/Icons/MetroIcons.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/Icons/SyncfusionIcons.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And this did work with no problems.

What an I doing wrong in terms of importing the resources from a different assembly that is causing the parsing error?

Comment: Are your files set to be copied to the output dir?

Comment: If you mean the files with the resources in the Common.Ui project, then no, they are not? What would that do? thanks.

Comment: No, the `Common.Ui` assembly. VS just sees the reference, for you application the referenced assembly needs to be next to your application's assembly.

Comment: I don't know if I understand exactly what you mean. The Common.Ui is not an actual external assembly. It is another project in my solution. How do I verify if it is set to be copied to output dir?

Comment: I set up the Common.Ui as a WPF UserControl Library project and placed the XAML files with the resources in it. Did I set it up wrong?

Comment: Did you set build action for ´MetroIcons.xaml´ and ´SyncfusionIcons.xaml´ to Resource? Is it the name of the assembly ´Common.Ui´. Could you provide more information about ´XamlParseException´? Is the ´Common.Ui´ referenced by your project?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually figured out the problem last night. You were right—the Common.Ui was not referenced correctly.  The user control I made was actually called on in a window in a different assembly. That assembly had the reference to the assembly containing the user control, but not a reference to the Common.Ui assembly. I didn't understand well enough how the framework handles references, and thought that they are cascading, but apparently I need to reference both assembly in the project were the window was running. Anyway, thanks again for your help.